# Filter to another sheet with criteria from 2 column based on cell name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to add ranges E:J from Fixture! sheet based on Team name only. F: is home games and J: is away games. I can add this to my other sheet as 2 seperate commands I wanted to know if it is possible to write this as one command/formula so it can capture the home and away games for TeamX in one go?

Many thanks

=filter(Fixture!E:J,Fixture!F:F="TeamX")
=filter(Fixture!E:J,Fixture!J:J="TeamX")

[=query(Fixture!E:J,"where F='Arsenal' or J='Arsenal'",0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UGZ3.png)

The info is copied to another sheet see below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nsVx.png)

So Rather than running filter twice to get to get home and away say for team Arsenal I wanted to capture all the info in one go. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I suggest you provide a sample table, file or screenshot about your data source, it will be more clearly to help us understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Thanks Lee, I have added image links

Answer (score 0):

The FILTER formula works with a TRUE/FALSE comparison to check if the array should be visible or not. There are multiple ways to get what you'd like, but this is the most understandable version (in my opinion):

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!E:J,IF((Sheet2!F:F="TeamX")=TRUE,TRUE,IF((Sheet2!J:J="TeamX")=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)))
```

So: if "TeamX" is found in column F, value = TRUE, otherwise check if column J contains "TeamX". Otherwise: FALSE

Comment: Hi Benjamin. This worked, thank you so much. This has saved a lot of time and effort. Very much appreciated!